# Getting antiseptic and antibiotic in Japan

Tags: japan, health, drugs

My wife's toe is inflamed and it hurts, so we need to get an antiseptic and an antibiotic.

But it seems that antiseptic/antibiotic sell is controlled in Japan, so it is not easy to buy from any drugstore.

1. Is that true?
2. How to get rather easily (directly from the drugstore) an antiseptic/antibiotic, or something that has the same effects?

The problem is not much what is the corresponding chemical component, but particularly:
(1) how to get it in Japan because of the different legislation on drugs
(2) what is the corresponding Japanese drugs name and drugs brand name

**Edit/Problem resolved: We used a drugs bought in homeland before departure: [*Dr.Jart+ - Cicapair - Derma Green Solution - Tiger Grass Cream*]. It was very efficient to calm the inflammation. And also we found an antiseptic also bought in homeland that we used preliminary to disinfect the skin**

Comment: FYI [Given the name of a US pharmaceutical drug, how can I know its equivalent in other countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168594/1810)

Comment: The antiseptic just kills micro-organisms on the skin. If our wife's skin is unbroken that seems unlikely to be helpful although unlikely to be harmful unless it causes irritation. An antibiotic will only help if this is a bacterial infection but there are multiple other causes of inflammation so you might do better to seek professional medical opinion if the condition persists.

Comment: Do you mean a systemic antibiotic (usually a pill) or a topical antibiotic (such as a cream--in the US would be "Neosporin" or "triple antibiotic cream")?

Comment: anti-septic creams and liquids are NOT antibiotics. Antibiotics are available on prescription only in any sane country, anti-septics are generally available in the supermarket along with other cleaning supplies. Penicilin e.g. is an antibiotic, rubbing alcohol works as an anti-septic.

Comment: @starckman a sane country will not allow antibiotics to be sold over the counter, as overuse will seriously deteriorate their effectiveness.

Answer (score 7):

Antibiotics are prescription drugs in Japan, so you will likely need to visit a doctor and get a prescription.  JNTO has a list of English-speaking clinics here:

https://www.jnto.go.jp/emergency/eng/mi_guide.html

Comment: What about topical antiseptics?

Comment: I think the OP probably means a topical antibiotic like Baramycin (which the internet seems to suggest is the Japanese equivalent to Neosporin and possibly available over the counter)...but I left a comment asking, so the OP can clarify. (Of course the discussion of if such topical creams are helpful or not is off topic here...)

Comment: [This is a product with Baramycin](https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/49252071) that should be available OTC at any large drug store for around 600 yen. I also think it is the one my wife uses for any generic cuts. Showing this web page at the counter should be enough and the staff will go find it for you.

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you very much, indeed we noticed this product, we will buy it and try.